# How to use Reconciliation Service API from Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, openrefine

[OpenRefine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenRefine) (formerly Google Refine) supports to match records to external identifiers via [Reconciliation Service API](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Reconciliation-Service-API), for instance to find Wikidata identifiers for entities described in table rows (see [Wikidata OpenRefine Service](https://tools.wmflabs.org/openrefine-wikidata/)). Is it possible to use the same API from a table in Google Sheets? I have not tried out Google apps scripts, could this be used to access a reconciliation API from sheets?

Comment: yes in general. look at apps script urlFetchApp. too broad until you show code and issues encountered.

Comment: I think @Jacob is looking for a ready addon, not how to program one. Such addon will be very useful indeed. I think this question belongs to superuser. com

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to export your document to csv and use http://okfnlabs.org/reconcile-csv/